# Qt Alt Codes not working?

Tags: c++, qt, keystroke

In my project I have a QLineEdit input widget. When I tried to enter an alt code (Alt+21) into that widget (which should be §) instead something very strange happens depending on how I press/hold the keys.

Here is every keystroke I took and the resulting character:

```
Alt: down
2: down
1: down
2: up
1: up
Alt: up

= I


Alt: down
2: down
2: up
1: down
1: up
Alt: up
= ú

Alt: down
2: down
1: down
1: up
Alt: up

= ╙

Alt: down
2: down
2: up
1: down
Alt: up

= ▌

Alt: down
2: down
1: down
Alt: up

= §
```

The same thing happens in my QPlainTextEdit. I NEED these alt codes to work in my program.

Sorry if I explained this poorly. The best way to see what I'm talking about is to just try it yourself. Go in Qt and try to enter § (Alt+21). It just doesn't work right.

Why is it doing this? How can I fix it?

EDIT: After some more tinkering, I have found out that the action of releasing a number acts like a value as well. Turns out I have to have NUM LOCK on for alt codes to work properly in Qt and the compiled programs.

Comment: Strange. Alt-21 gives § here (QPlainTextEdit). How does Alt-21 work in Wordpad or Notepad on your PC?

Comment: It works as expected. § pops up no problem in Notepad. Im using Qt 5.0.2

Comment: I've tested almost every program on my computer, only Qt and the compiled Qt programs dont work. Even in the Qt designer is doesn't work.

Comment: I have 5.3.2. Compile the first example project "Application Example" (looks like notepad). Does Alt-21 work there?

Comment: No it still does not work properly.

Comment: Please don't give up on me :(  I am absolutely dumbfounded.

Comment: Found something out, when I do the first technique I mentioned, it actually does put a §. But if I release both 2 and 1 before I release Alt, then it becomes a I.

Comment: No idea. I can not reproduce it. Try upgrading drivers, scan for malware and like that.

Comment: I edited my post with some more info. Turns out it only happens when numlock is off. Try turning it off and see if it messes up for you to.

Comment: It seems to work with numlock *off* too but all sites suggest to have numlock *on* for it to work.